# The quicker I go up, the sooner I’ll go down - Riddle

Tags: riddle

I got this riddle (and a few more) from an old video game. I had a few ideas but none fit the entire riddle perfectly...

> The quicker I go up.
>   The sooner I’ll go down.
>   I’m a weave of edges,
>   A center of wholes.
>   I’ll die of exhaustion,
>   Some say a love immature,
>   And color the cheeks,
>   In a passion untold.

Can you name me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> A Flame

The quicker I go up

The sooner I’ll go down.

> Flames that catch quickly tend to burn out soon.

I’m a weave of edges,

> Flames weave, and the edges are the brightest part, so they're what you see the most of.

A center of wholes.

> Only clue I'm unsure about.  Unless it relates back to the Sun, which is a flaming thing at the center of the solar system as per @Karm's guess.

I’ll die of exhaustion,

> Flames will die down when they've exhausted their fuel or available oxygen.

Some say a love immature,

> A "flame" is a word you might use to describe a former romantic partner.

And color the cheeks

> Flames provide warmth

In a passion untold.

> Flames of passion, pretty much speaks for itself.

Answer (score 14):

My guess is:

> The Sun

The quicker I go up
The sooner I’ll go down.

> The sooner the sun comes up the earlier it will go down

I’m a weave of edges,

> Flames are the visible chemical reaction, where they  may appear to flicker or weave

A center of wholes.

> Center of our solar system

I’ll die of exhaustion,

> The sun will eventually run out of resources to burn and therefore die

Some say a love immature,

> Our sun is relatively young by comparison of other stars

And colour the cheeks

> The sun heats us when cold

In a passion untold.

> Film reference - Passion in the Sun (1964) - IMDb

Comment: Not sure about the second one. Rot13(Gur rneyvre gur fha evfrf, gur ***yngre*** vg frgf).

Comment: Hmm, the subject of your answer has lived half its life expectancy already.

Answer (score 5):

Not totally sure

> Blood

The quicker I go up

The sooner I’ll go down.

> When the heart is beating faster the blood flows faster up or down.

I’m a weave of edges,

A center of wholes.

> In cut blood clots into a scab. Otherwise, it is in no contact with the air.

This is the part I am a bit unsure:

I’ll die of exhaustion,

Some say a love immature,

And color the cheeks

In a passion untold.

> I see there two things although there is no points between. Dying of exhaustion means dying of blood loss or that the blood dies outside the body (in a normal situation). The rest is about blushing.

Comment: rot13(Oybbq pryyf ynfgf sbe n ovg, naq gura trgf cnffrq bhg bs gur obql. Urnegf naq inyragvarf ner bsgra jung puvyqera hfr gb fvtavsl ybir.)

Comment: That's the [wrong word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exsanguination) for that kind of fatality. Although it can lead to it, your word is never fatal. Generally, cardiac arrest, so close enough I guess.

Comment: @Mazura I connected it in my mind with the verb exhaust which does work as a synonym for depleting and drain.

Answer (score 0):

(I just wanted to answer the title, so I had to make all this stuff up. The parting line really did suck though)

The quicker I go up, The sooner I’ll go down.

> That's because you're a stupid toy; **inflatable punching bag** clown.

I’m a weave of edges,

> Hitting the parting line on the side always kinda hurt. Watch out for the bob and weave, yo.

A center of wholes.

> Inside it's just air. The whole center is a hole.

I’ll die of exhaustion,

> Literally, because all that's inside is air. These toys last about five minutes. It *will* happen.

Some say a love immature, And color the cheeks, In a passion untold.

> Most people *say* they abhor violence, and would call those who don't immature. The passion untold is the unwillingness to disclose the elation experienced while committing acts of violence. With their animalistic instincts laid bare, likely they will blush.